# Правильное расположение текстуры в соответствии с объектом

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, libgdx

Проблема заключается в том, что у меня не выходит корректно рисовать текстуру внутри объекта.

Т.е мне нужно получить вот такой вот результат (*на картинке пример из интернета*):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же рассматривать на примере моей игры, то конечный результат должен быть вот таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня никак не выходит рисовать текстуры так, чтобы они были внутри объекта **CyrcleShape**.

Изначально так у меня вообще вот такое выходило:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне удалось вручную подкорректировать положение текстуры. Только если при этом игрок совершает прыжок, то `y` **текстуры** немного отстает по высоте от `y` **CircleShape`а**.

Причина этого мне крайне непонятна. Единственное, что у меня есть пару предположений.

**1-ой предположение:**
Неправильное изменение координат в классе **PlayScreen**.

```
// в данном классе у меня есть обработчик событий пользователя, с помощью которых он управляет игроком
@Override
public void handleInput(float dt) {

    // do nothing
    player.setStay(true);

    // jumping
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        player.setJump(true);
        player.setStay(false);
        light.setPosition(player.b2body.getPosition().x, player.b2body.getPosition().y);
    }
    // turn right
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) &&
            player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) {
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
       // player.getVelocity().x += Player.SPEED;
        player.setMoveRight(true);
        player.setMoveleft(false);
        player.setStay(false);
    }
    // turn left
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) &&
            player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2) {
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        //player.getVelocity().x =- Player.SPEED;
        player.setMoveRight(false);
        player.setMoveleft(true);
        player.setStay(false);
    }

    // escape button - game on pause
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE)) {
        GameLoader.currentIndex = GameLoader.MENU_PAUSE_STATE;
        GameLoader.gameLoader.addState(new MenuPauseScene());
        GameLoader.gameLoader.setNewState();
    }


}
```

**2-ое предположение:** Некорректный рендеринг и обновление позиции самой текстуры в классе **Player**

```
 // при рисовании уровня, сначала я вызываю update(), а потом уже render()
 public void update(float dt) {

    setPosition((b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2 ) *1, (b2body.getPosition().y - getHeight() /2  ) * MyGdxGame.PPM);
}

 public void render(SpriteBatch batch, float dt) {
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    // загружаю анимацию и как раз пытаюсь костыльно выравнивать текстуру:
    // чтобы она была внутри фигуры, а не еще где-нибудь
    if (stay) {
        currentFrame = stayAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, getX() + 170 , getY() - 27, 300f, 300f );
    }

    if (moveRight) {
        currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, getX() + 170 , getY() - 27, 300f, 300f );
    }

    if (moveleft) {
        currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, getX() + 170 , getY() - 27, 300f, 300f );
    }

    if (isJump) {
        currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, getX() + 170 , getY() - 27, 300f, 300f );
    }
}
```

**3-е предположение:** Мои текстуры неправильные

Вот сами текстуры, которые я вчера нарисовал

[ресурс № 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/28drlzmp25djfiu/Hero2.png?dl=0)
[ресурс № 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cao6kyie4zuurur/hero_stay.png?dl=0)

Причем самое интересное, что неправильный рендеринг текстуры (отставание от объекта) происходит только при прыжке. Если же игрок просто ходит - то ничего такого не замечается.

Никак не могу понять то, почему у меня текстура не может перемещаться синхронно с **CircleShape-ом**.

**P.S:** Я только недавно начал изучать **libGDX**, поэтому прошу меня правильно понять.

Comment: По-моему вы потеряли pixels per meter и при отрисовке не берете коэффициент в расчет

Comment: @katso А вы не знаете как это можно исправить?

Comment: @katso Сейчас только что заметил, что текстура отстает от объекта только при прыжке. Если просто ходить, то все будет нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалось в `OrthographicCamera`.

Ошибка была в том, что у меня неправильно была настроена ортографическая камера. Именно из-за этого у меня не было синхронности в движении самой текстуры и **CircleShape**.

Тем самым, нужно было просто правильно настроить камеру.

И вместо этого:

```
    gameCam = new OrthographicCamera((MyGdxGame.V_WIDTH / MyGdxGame.PPM) * 2, (MyGdxGame.V_HEIGHT / MyGdxGame.PPM )* 2 );
    gamePort = new FitViewport(
    MyGdxGame.V_WIDTH / MyGdxGame.PPM,
    MyGdxGame.V_HEIGHT / MyGdxGame.PPM, gameCam);
    hud = new Hud(game.batch);
```

Написать вот такой код:

```
gameCam = new OrthographicCamera((MyGdxGame.V_WIDTH / MyGdxGame.PPM) * 2, (MyGdxGame.V_HEIGHT / MyGdxGame.PPM )* 2 );
gameCam.position.set(player.getPosition().x,player.getPosition().y,0);
```